# parse the result of grep in a browser with javascript

Tags: javascript, linux, browser, grep

I want to parse the result of a grep command in a browser.
Something like `grep -nriI "hello" myFolder`
The result is a multiline string:

```
/home/user/folder/file1:1:hello world
/home/user/folder/file2:1:world hello
/home/user/folder/folder/file3:1:bonjour=hello
```

First I split the lines to have an array. And parse it with this regex: `/^(.*?)\:(\d*)\:(.*?)$/`

I have some problems.

1. Parse will not work for result with funny char like double point (:)
2. When I grep a file, I do not get `pah:line number:content` but only `line number:content` so it make the regex more complicated (there is no named group in javascript regex).

Has someone already a good parser or a project which parse it. It has to work in a browser...

I will make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My grep (on Ubuntu Linux) has some options that could help, though neither of them are POSIX standard.

For ambiguous output:

```
   -Z, --null
          Output  a  zero  byte  (the ASCII NUL character) instead of the character
          that normally follows a file name.  For example, grep -lZ outputs a  zero
          byte  after  each  file  name  instead of the usual newline.  This option
          makes the  output  unambiguous,  even  in  the  presence  of  file  names
          containing  unusual  characters  like  newlines.  This option can be used
          with commands like find -print0, perl  -0,  sort  -z,  and  xargs  -0  to
          process arbitrary file names, even those that contain newline characters.
```

For the missing filename:

```
   -H, --with-filename
          Print the file name for each match.  This is the default  when  there  is
          more than one file to search.
```

So use `grep -nriIHZ` and update your regex to something like this (untested):

```
/^(.*)\0(\d+):(.*)$/
```

Comment: The grep is done on the server, can I transfert the \0 to the client ? I try it and currently \0 does not appear in the response of the server.

Comment: It should be possible. Not all viewers show null bytes properly. Try running it through a hex viewer to be sure you're seeing the output properly.

Comment: yeah it works :) like you said ```grep -nriIHZ``` with ```/^(.*)\0(\d+):(.*)$/``` perfect. The network console of chrome don't display it but the ASCII NULL character is present.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
var regex = /^([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*)$/;
var lines = [
    '/home/user/folder/file1:1:hello world',
    '/home/user/folder/file2:1:world hello',
    '/home/user/folder/folder/file3:1:bonjour=hello'
];
var output = $('#output');

for(var i in lines)
{
    var result = lines[i].match(regex).slice(1);

    output.append(result.join(' - ') + "\n");
}
```

Result:

```
/home/user/folder/file1 - 1 - hello world
/home/user/folder/file2 - 1 - world hello
/home/user/folder/folder/file3 - 1 - bonjour=hello
```

Works just fine for me, which probably means I didn't understand your question. Hopefully this helps anyway. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CVLk8/

The `slice(1)` after the above regex match is to get rid of the first result in the array, which is the full match.

Comment: not bad but there is a problem when I grep just a file. I can test if the second item in the result is empty. ```'1:hello world'``` gives ```["1", "", "hello world"]``` see here: http://jsfiddle.net/CVLk8/2/ Why is you regex better ?

Comment: it also failed with path with colon like this: ```/home/user/folder/fil:e1```. Thanks :)

Comment: I think you should consider file names with colons invalid - at least for your own sanity. Also notice that I'm using a simpler RegEx than your are, simply matching three groups that don't contain ":"